# Macbook Pro hanging on Boot Screen After Driver Installation

Tags: macbook-pro, driver, kernel-extensions

After installing a USB 3.0 to VGA  driver for an external monitor, my Macbook won't start up after rebooting. I download fl2000 1.4.2 off of frescologic's site: https://support.frescologic.com/portal/en/kb/articles/fl2000-mac-driver-beta-release

When I rebooted my mac, it hung up on the boot page with the apple logo. The boot process hangs even though the loading bar is completely filled. I can't start my computer now so I'm trying to delete the driver via recovery mode. I think it is one of the kext files in Library/Extensions, but there are so many and none of them say frescologic.

My macbook pro is a 2015 model with Mac OS Mojave installed. Unfortunately I don't have a filevault backup so uninstalling the driver is my only hope of recovering my work. Is there an easy way to identify this kernel extension and am I even looking in the right place?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong `/System/Library/Extensions`. You've booted into macOS Recovery, which lives on its own volume separate from your normal boot volume. This means that all filesystem paths are relative to the root of the *Recovery* volume, *not* your boot volume.

**Try first `cd`ing into `/Volumes/YourBootVolumeName` and continuing from there.** When you find the appropriate KEXT(s), you can delete them or move them outside of the `Extensions/` directory.

You will then also need to run the following command in order to update the kernel extension cache, otherwise you'll still be trying to boot as if you never deleted the Fresco Logic KEXTs: **`kextcache -update-volume /Volumes/YourBootVolumeName`**

Comment: In my case it was sufficient to remove the file: rm /Library/Extensions/FL2000.kext. My mac booted up fine after that. I realized I was in the wrong directory, glad I didn't delete anything there!

Comment: there is no  better explicable as that

Answer (score 2):

The package comes with an uninstaller script, from which I was able to scavenge this list of file locations & deletion commands…

```
sudo rm -f /usr/local/libexec/screen_capture

sudo rm -f /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.frescologic.screen_capture.plist
sudo rm -f /Library/LaunchAgents/com.frescologic.screen_capture.plist

sudo rm -r /Library/LaunchAgents/com.frescologic.screen_capture-prelogin.plist

sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/FL2000.kext

sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/IOProxyVideoCard.kext

sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/IOProxyFramebuffer.kext

echo Please restart your computer for changes to take effect.
```

You should be able to run these from terminal

Comment: OP can't get to Terminal due to the boot hang.

Comment: @pion - You can get to Terminal from Recovery. I presume that's how they got the information in the OP.

Comment: The script won't work as-is from Recovery

Comment: You're not really being very helpful here...

Comment: For the script to work, you need to remove `sudo` and prepend the boot volume path to each path passed to `rm`. Finally, `kextcache` needs to be manually invoked because `kextd` doesn't monitor non-root volumes for changes to `Extensions`.

Comment: Thank you this is the command that worked for me: rm -rf /Library/Extensions/FL2000.kext. My main issue was being in the wrong directory